# Is it possible to add a \ in the body of the message?

Tags: stocktwits

I'm using the stocktwits api to pull tweets and process them. When there are quotes in the body of the message the JSON parser gives errors. Is it possible to add a \ before the extra quotes in the body.
For example:

```
{"body":"ChOTD-11/3/16 CBOE "Equity Put":Call Ratio ISEE Call:Put Ratio Hits Extreme > 1.00 $SPY $SPX"}
```

Here the quotes around "Equity Put" should been escaped
like this \"Equity Put\"

```
{"body":"ChOTD-11/3/16 CBOE \"Equity Put\":Call Ratio ISEE Call:Put Ratio Hits Extreme > 1.00 $SPY $SPX"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response comes as an html encoded string.

For example:

`"Test with &quot;quotes&quot;"`

You need to be using a JSON serializer that decodes these html entities when parsing, which will turn it into

`"Test with \"quotes\""`

Comment: {"body":"What is "normalization" policy and what does it mean for December? http://www.blackgolddisease.com/2016/11/normalization-versus-rate-hike-policy.html $SPX $DJIA $COMPQ $FED $TNX $MACRO $USDX"} another example this comes straight from the api, no encoding.

Comment: What are you using to call the API? Whatever you are using is most likely doing its own serialization and not showing you the real raw response body.

Comment: This is wat I'm using to call the api: https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/dax.json

Comment: I'm asking what tool are you using to call the API. I believe your tool is already taking the html entities and decoding them, which is why you're seeing the response normalized.

Comment: Jsoup is literally an html parser, therefore you aren't seeing the raw response, you're seeing a parsed response after Jsoup has parsed it. I suggest calling the API where you can read the raw response and do what you need with it.